# How does C++ interact with the Operating System?

Tags: c++

Like how JavaScript is able to manipulate the DOM because the browser exposes the DOM to JavaScript in the form of an Object. Is that the same way C++ is able to do things like draw on the screen? Does the Operating System create a C++ interface in the form of C++ classes or does the Operating System have some generic interface that my specific version of C++ knows how to implement?

[image]

Comment: Through [system calls](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/System_call)

Comment: One of the closers please explain how this is off-topic? The asker may want to know how to avoid closure in the future. I'd tell him what the problem is, but frankly its a mystery to me too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you look at things from the OS's persepctive, it provides API's for things like graphics, IPC, and IO, with a common interface. Typicaly this takes the form of linkable subroutines using a calling convention standard to that OS. People who create languages (compilers or interpreters) will provide their own code that interfaces to those subroutines, so that you can use them in your user code. For C compilers, typically this takes the form of just calling those OS routines directly. For higher-level languages, often there will be a layer of code that takes care of some of the nitty details for you, be it converting cookies to classes, or a complete portable high-level facility like you might see in some scripting languages.

In C++'s case, generally you look in the STL and see if there's something there you can use. If not, your typical fallback is to call the OS routines directly like a C user would. It used to be the case that most things, outside of basic text I/O, were not available in the STL, so you have to fall back to making direct OS calls. However, recent revisions of the language have started adding more and more interfaces to typical OS functionality to the STL. Also, often there's stuff in [Boost](http://www.boost.org/) that will do want you want, if you don't mind downloading it, installing it, and figuring out how it works.

Comment: thanks for that! huge boost in my understanding.

Answer (score 5):

C++ interacts quite little with the operating system. For instance, it has no idea about screens or drawing – although additional libraries, such as OpenGL, may.

Standard C++03 essentially restricts its interaction with the host system to memory management (allocation and deallocation), file stream operations, date and time access and localisation information (I might forget something though). C++11 adds a few more cases, such as handling of threaded code and access to the [system’s random device](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki//dev/random) (if available).

All these are completely unspecified and every C++ implementation has its own code, depending on the system it’s running on. One important interface that lots of C++ implementations are using is called [POSIX](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/POSIX), which exposes a C API.

Answer (score 2):

> Does the Operating System create a C++ interface in the form of C++
>   classes

No, the classes are defined by various C++ libraries, including the standard library.

> or does the Operating System have some generic interface that my
>   specific version of C++ knows how to implement?

I suppose you can say it like that.  Operating systems will have lower level APIs (perhaps function-call based) which are then wrapped up as class libraries.